# function returning [object Promise]

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the value of the first function, and use as variable on the second function, but it's showing this `[object Promise]`.

```
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(fetchAndStream(event.request))
});

async function handleRequest(request) {
      var uri = request.url.replace(/^https:\/\/.*?\//gi, "/");
      return uri;
}

async function fetchAndStream() {

    uri = handleRequest();
    console.log(uri);
    // Fetch from origin server.
    let response = await fetch('http://blablabla.com/' + uri);

    const responseInit = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="file.m3u"',
        }
    };

    // ... and deliver our Response while that's running.
    return new Response(response.body, responseInit)
}
```

Comment: `handleRequest` is `async`. Why? It doesn't do anything asynchronous. If you really want it to be async then `await` the result but also make sure it does an asynchronous operation. Otherwise, just don't have it as async.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your functions incorrectly without arguments. Your handleRequest takes an argument request in your function declaration

```
async function handleRequest(request)
```

In your event listener you are calling the callback with an argument

```
fetchAndStream(event.request)
```

But you don't take any arguments here.

```
async function fetchAndStream() {

    uri = handleRequest();
    console.log(uri);
```

Since you have used your function handleRequest with async. It returns a promise wrapper which will await the execution, which I have doubts it will complete from there. The wrapper is like a placeholder which will be filled once your promise completes but since you are not calling the functions properly. Hence you are getting the output.